# std::bind with explicit return type

Tags: c++, c++11

One version of [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) allows the caller to provide an explicit return type:

```
template< class R, class F, class... Args >
/*unspecified*/ bind( F&& f, Args&&... args );
```

What is a good example when one may use (or be forced to use) this version of `std::bind`?

Comment: Back in TR1, before C++11 and `decltype()` existed, in many cases you can't deduce the return type and must specify it explicitly.

Comment: @T.C.So is it left as legacy code ?

Comment: Mostly, I think. There are probably cases where you really want to force a conversion (e.g., for a negative number, converting from `int`->`unsigned int` -> `unsigned long long` is usually different from converting from `int` directly to `unsigned long long`, or to bypass the "only one user-defined conversion" rule for implicit conversion sequences), but it's pretty rare.

Comment: `std::bind` itself is mostly legacy.  Its strange "magic" with recursive bind expressions means, to me, that I cannot use it as a pure binder anyhow.

Comment: use lambda expression and forget about `std::bind`...